# Forge Model Derivatives: How Long to Wait for 202?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm using the endpoint `:urn/metadata/:guid` and I receive a 202 status from the server. I keep requesting it, but it does not appear to progress at all (202 is always sent back). The file I'm using is relatively large (1.7 gb) but I am only asking for the metadata of one 2D floor plan. I am using forceget = true. Is this an issue on my end or Autodesk's end?

Comment: Now I'm getting a 404 error what I try to retrieve metadata from the view.

Comment: Can you retrieve the urn's manifest properly?
Please send the urn and guid to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com for further investigation.